# A problem with the user input during the random forest classifier demonstration

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, user-input

I got over 90% accuracy with the Random Forest classifier, but I worry the rest of the algorithms give much lower results:
[Metrics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eIqLc.png) [image: CV]
But this is not the main concern. The problem is that when I used user inputs, the prediction was 100 percent wrong. The order of the columns of the user input corresponds to the training data set columns' places.

```
model = RandomForestClassifier()
model.fit(X_train, y_train)
prediction = model.predict(X_test)
acc = accuracy_score(y_test, prediction)   # output: 0.91

X_test_user = df_user_compounds_1.to_numpy()
user_input_predictions_1 = model.predict(X_test_user) # 
user_input_predictions_1    # output: array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0], dtype=int64), but it should be: array([1, 1, 1, 1, 1],dtype=int64)
```

Does anyone have any idea why this is happening?

The dataset is preprocessed - no missing values, no duplicates, it was balanced with RandomOverSampler, scaled with MinMaxScaler, no negative values and contains 11 features/7K rows.

...........

Thank you so much @ElvinJafarov. These are parts from df_user_compounds_1, and X_test after your suggestion.

[image: X_test]

Since I had already used MinMaxScaler(), I had to add two more rows to df_user_compounds_1, containing the corresponding min and max values to  simulate identical scaling to the original one. I found the max and min values through df.describe(include="all"), concatenated these two rows to the user inputs data frame and scaled [image: User input preprocessing]

I am happy with the result: first 5 must be 1, i.e. 4 out of 5 [image: Result]

Comment: Show part of df_user_compounds_1, and X_test

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, it is okay that different algorithms give different accuracy rate.

Secondly, in your case, there might be several reasons.

1. You have scaled your inputs in data but not in **df_user_compounds_1**
2. your model might be overfitted
3. dataset was preprocessed differently than df_user_compounds_1

Thirdly, this is not how you approach to choose a model. You have to try [K-Fold Cross validationn](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/cross_validation.html) ,  [hyperparameter tuning](https://aws.amazon.com/what-is/hyperparameter-tuning/#:%7E:text=Hyperparameter%20tuning%20allows%20data%20scientists,the%20model%20as%20a%20hyperparameter.)

Comment: Thank you Elvin !!! You are geniuses. You hit the Bull's Eye! Yes, I haven`t scaled the user input :D Thank you so much!!!

Comment: @MariqIvanova please approve and upvote my answer to help everybody who will face same issue with you

Comment: I upvoted it but: Thanks for the feedback! You need at least 15 reputation to cast a vote, but your feedback has been recorded.

Comment: ig you can approve ,not upvote. but thanks for tryinh

Comment: I beg your pardon Elvin. I didn't know the procedure "approve/accept" here. I think , I`ve done it now.